# mysql select * by index is very slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table like this:

```
create table test (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    idcard varchar(30),
    name varchar(30)，
    custom_value varchar(50),
    index i1(idcard)
)
```

I insert 30,000,000 rows to the table

and then I execute:

```
  select * from test where idcard='?'
```

The statement cost 12 seconds to return

when I use iostat to monitor disk

the read speed is about 6 mb/s while the util is 94%

is any way to optimize it?

Comment: Are you using any wildcards in your parameter value?

Comment: How many actual rows are returned?

Comment: What MySQL version? Is this an innodb table? What innodb_buffer_pool_size do you have?

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN {query}` output.

Comment: How did you measure 12 seconds? Are you running on the client on the same node as the server?

Comment: Have you tried using a partial index on idcard? Using size 10 or something?

Comment: How many rows have the value `'?'` for idcard? If it's more than ~20%, MySQL will not use the index, it'll do a table-scan instead. You need to get the EXPLAIN report as @danblack suggested.

Comment: @BillKarwin abount 3000 rows, with explain, it use index i1

Comment: Is the string really `?`, or are you binding a value?

Answer (score 2):

12 seconds *may* be realistic.

Assumptions about the question:

- A total of 30M rows, but only 3000 rows in the resultset.
- Not enough room to cache things in RAM *or* you are running from a cold start.
- InnoDB or MyISAM (the analysis is the same; the details are radically different).
- Any `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for `idcard`.
- `INDEX(idcard)` exists and is used in the query.
- HDD disk drive, not SSD.

Here's a breakdown of the processing:

1. Go to the index, find the first entry with `?`, scan forward until hitting an entry that is not `?` (about 3K rows later).
2. For each of those 3K items, reach into the table to find all the columns (cf `SELECT *`.
3. Deliver them.

Step 1:  Fast.

Step 2:  This is (based on the assumption of not being cached) costly.  It may involve about 3K disk hits.  For an HDD, that would be about 30 seconds.  So, 12 seconds could imply some of the stuff was cached or happened to be near each other.

Step 3:  This is a network cost, which I am not considering.

Run the query a second time.  It may take only 1 second the this time -- because all 3K blocks are cached in RAM!  And iostat will show zero activity!

> is any way to optimize it?

Well...

- You already have the best index.
- What are you going to do with 3000 rows all at once?  Is this a one-time task?
- When using InnoDB, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of available RAM, but not so big that it leads to swapping.  What is its setting, and how much RAM do you have and what else is running on the machine?
- Could you do more of the task while you are fetching the 3K rows?
- Switching to SSDs would help, but I don't like hardware bandaids; they are not reusable.
- How big is the table (in GB) -- perhaps 3GB data plus index?  (`SHOW TABLE STATUS`.)  If you can't make the buffer_pool big enough for it, *and* you have a variety of queries that compete for different parts of this (and other) tables, then more RAM may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like an I/O limitation than something that could be solved by adding indices. What will improve the speed is change the collation of the idcard column to latin1_bin. This uses only 1 byte per character. It also uses binary comparison which is faster than case insensitive comparison.

Only do this if you have no special characters in the idcard column, because the character set of latin1 is quite limited.

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN `idcard` `idcard` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE 'latin1_bin' AFTER `id`;
```

Furthermore the ROW_FORMAT=FIXED also improves the speed. ROW_FORMAT=FIXED is not available using the InnoDB engine, but it is with MyISAM. The resulting table I now have is shown below. It's 5 times quicker (80% less time) with select statements than the initial table.

Note that I also changed the collation for 'name' and 'custom_value' to latin1_bin. This does make quite a difference in speed in my test setup, and I'm still figuring out why.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idcard` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `name` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `custom_value` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `i1` (`idcard`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=FIXED ;
```

Comment: Please do not advocate MyISAM.  `FIXED` usually does not speed things up; instead, it slows varchars down because it leads to more I/O.  Please do not advocate latin1; we are well into the era of UTF-8.

Comment: @RickJames I've tested it and ROW_FORMAT=FIXED does speed things quite a lot in my test setup. About UTF-8 I somewhat agree with you. But I also found that using latin1-bin gives quite a speed boost and the poster wants speed.

Comment: Did you build a full 30M rows?  What value of `key_buffer_size`?  How much RAM?  Did you time each thing twice?  Was the Query cache off?  (I am fishing for whether you might have "caching" benefits that are confusing the results.

Answer (score -1):

You may try adding the three other columns in the select clause to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON test (idcard, id, name, custom_value);
```

The three columns other than `idcard` are being added to allow the index to *cover* everything being selected.  The problem with your current index is that it is only on `idcard`.  This means that once MySQL has traversed down to each leaf node in the index, it would have to do another seek back to the clustered index to lookup the values of all columns mentioned in the `select *`.  As a result of this, MySQL may choose to ignore the index completely.  The suggestion I made above avoids this additional seek.

Comment: Amused by the downvote, even more amused by the lack of reason.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but indexing all columns seems like a very bad practice. Your indexes will not only use more space, but more memory. Inserts and updates will be slower as well.

Comment: @EnricoDias There are only 4 columns in total.  The OP's index won't probably help.  I would not suggest covering more than 2-3 columns.

Comment: I did a quick test in my machine with some random data and using no indexes was slightly faster than indexing all columns. I really see no point in indexing the 4 columns.

Comment: What is the cardinality of `idcard` in your "test?"  How do you even know what the OP's data is?  What is the significance of your test?

Comment: I don't know the OP's data, I just used some random data. As I said, I'm no expert, I just don't see a point in having a table where everything is an index.

Comment: I do not see a reason for indexing all columns as well. Usually, you use such indexes to prevent data lookups (everything getting from index at cost of increased storage usage and slowing inserts/updates). However, OP situation looks different (I believe there are not many records per idcard in the table) and if query returns not too many records it would be not too many data-lookups. If there are many records returned, the index would not help anyway as the bottleneck would be in sending response. P.S. I have not downvoted your answer.